# Schedule fraction of a macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro on VBA and I need to pause the macro at a certain point and to make it go ahead at a given time. I am using Ontime but my issue is that I don't want to restart the macro at the given time nor I can create a separate macro for the rest of the code and schedule it. I need it to be a unique macro with a Stop and Continue at (given time) statements. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a need for the previous code to be halted, can it just be split.  Something like on time calling a 9am routine, then another ontime in that one for the 2nd part.  Or use public variables to hold what you need and call, can you show the code is probably best :)

Comment: Actually I cannot show the code, I am at work maybe later I can... The problem is that I cannot split the macro because it needs to be everything inside one unique macro

Comment: If you just halt the macro, it will halt the entire thing, so i dont think this is the best solution.  I'd think more about restructuring the macro, into 2 halves and call what is required first time on one ontime, then the 2nd.

Comment: Note that *"it needs to be everything inside one unique macro"* is no explanation why you think it should. Actually I cannot think of any reason why this should *not* be possible. Please be more clear/specific why.

Comment: Ok, the first part runs a function which produces a pop-up I cannot mute (I tried everything, it is a built-in tool), the second part runs the same function but after the first call the function does not produce the pop-up anymore. If I split the macro, the different calls to the function would be like the first call and so the pop-ups would appear every time

Comment: I think I managed, I created an infinite loop which does nothing and continues until the wished time